# Kendo UI combobox not setting item by value

Tags: jquery, combobox, kendo-ui

I have an kendoAutocomplete control on my page.
It has its dataValueField set to "ClientID" which I store in my viewModel.
When a user selects the desired Client I then look up related agents and I populate them into a kendoComboBox which also has a dataValueField of "ClientID".
Basically if the selected Client is also an Agent then they are to be automatically selected in the combobox so that they'll be the Agent for themselves if you see what I mean.
I've tried a number of things:

```
$("#agentList").data("kendoComboBox").select(viewModel.get("NewClientID"));
```

This doesn't work.
For testing purposes I tried.

```
$("#agentList").data("kendoComboBox").select(0);
```

This does do something - it selects the first item in the combobox but that's not what I'm after so I guess the "select" method is setting based on index.
I've also tried using "value" like so:
    $("#agentList").data("kendoComboBox").value(viewModel.get("NewClientID"));
and just for good measure I tried hard coding the value I'm using:

```
$("#agentList").data("kendoComboBox").value(900224);
```

None of these things are producing the desired outcome.
It might be the version of Kendo UI I'm using doesn't support this?
The Kendo UI plugin I have outputs to Chrome's console that the version I'm using is "2014.1.318".
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.
**EDIT:**

```
var searchName = viewModel.get("SearchName()");
combobox.select(function (dataItem) {
    return dataItem.DisplayName === searchName;
});
```

Possibly not bullet proof but this appears to be working.